# GLSL: #define vs const

Tags: glsl

What is the difference between `#define NAME VALUE` and `const int NAME = VALUE` in GLSL `410 core`?

As far as I can see, they both create a constant integer.

Comment: Since glsl is based on the syntax of c, I suspect [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3216752/2209007) will answer your question.

Comment: @Samurai8 thank you! Should I delete this question?

Comment: I *think* this question is on-topic, but I am not all that familiar with this particular stackexchange. If the question is on-topic, it does not matter it has already an answer on a different SE site; just self-answer this question with what you have learned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#define NAME VALUE` is a macro, where all instances of `NAME` are replaced with `VALUE` by the pre-processor.

The compiler handles constants. This ensures type safety.